# Is it possible to increase the dimension from 2D to 3D?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a vector [1,10], how can I increase the dimension to a three dimensional matrix. What I want is to have A(:,:,1)=[1,10] such that size(A)=[1,2,1]. I understand to use reshape/permute, but the size of A always gives [1,2].

Comment: Just as a tip: MATLAB matrices are infinite dimensionals. Try  `size(A,1234)`

Comment: MATLAB removes trailing singleton dimensions so no this is not possible.  However, it is possible in NumPy though.

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements in the output returned by the size function `size(A)` will always be 2 or the number of the highest dimension greater than 1 (whichever is highest).
This is because all the sizes in unspecified dimensions can (mathematically speaking) be seen as being 1. This is also why `size(A,17)` will return `1` and why `A(1,2)` is the same as `A(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)`.